# Chamar ficheiro CSV com 3 colunas no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando chamar o arquivo `temperature.csv` no Python mas mostra com erros, ou seja, eu queria que aparecesse as três colunas.

O código que fiz foi o seguinte:

```
import pandas as pd 
dataset= pd.read_csv("c:\\Users\\smnm2\\Documents\\temperature.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1", header=None)
print(dataset)
```

O resultado foi:

```
runfile('C:/Users/smnm2/chamada.py', wdir='C:/Users/smnm2')
                                                     0
0                                Timestamp;Temperature
1    Tue Apr 23 2019 11:49:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
2    Tue Apr 23 2019 11:50:15 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
3    Tue Apr 23 2019 11:50:15 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
4    Tue Apr 23 2019 11:50:55 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
5    Tue Apr 23 2019 11:51:45 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
6    Tue Apr 23 2019 11:52:35 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
7    Tue Apr 23 2019 11:53:05 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
8    Tue Apr 23 2019 11:53:45 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
9    Tue Apr 23 2019 11:55:01 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
10   Tue Apr 23 2019 11:55:01 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
11   Tue Apr 23 2019 11:55:32 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
12   Tue Apr 23 2019 11:56:32 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
13   Tue Apr 23 2019 11:56:32 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
14   Tue Apr 23 2019 11:57:17 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
15   Tue Apr 23 2019 11:57:59 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
16   Tue Apr 23 2019 11:59:09 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
17   Tue Apr 23 2019 11:59:19 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
18   Tue Apr 23 2019 11:59:59 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
19   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:00:39 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
20   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:00:59 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
21   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:01:29 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
22   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:01:39 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
23   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:02:26 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
24   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:02:46 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
25   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:02:56 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
26   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:08:01 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
27   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:10:23 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
28   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:11:46 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
29   Tue Apr 23 2019 12:14:16 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
..                                                 ...
578  Wed Apr 24 2019 17:49:02 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
579  Wed Apr 24 2019 17:51:40 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
580  Wed Apr 24 2019 17:51:40 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
581  Wed Apr 24 2019 17:53:10 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
582  Wed Apr 24 2019 17:55:47 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
583  Wed Apr 24 2019 17:55:47 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
584  Wed Apr 24 2019 17:56:17 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
585  Wed Apr 24 2019 17:59:17 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
586  Wed Apr 24 2019 17:59:17 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
587  Wed Apr 24 2019 18:02:17 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
588  Wed Apr 24 2019 18:03:57 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
589  Wed Apr 24 2019 18:03:57 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
590  Wed Apr 24 2019 18:05:12 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
591  Wed Apr 24 2019 18:05:27 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
592  Wed Apr 24 2019 18:08:12 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
593  Wed Apr 24 2019 18:08:27 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
594  Wed Apr 24 2019 18:11:12 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
595  Wed Apr 24 2019 18:14:12 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
596  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:13:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
597  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:14:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
598  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:17:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
599  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:23:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
600  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:26:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
601  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:29:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
602  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:32:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
603  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:35:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
604  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:41:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
605  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:44:31 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
606  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:50:32 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...
607  Fri Apr 26 2019 09:56:32 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00);...

[608 rows x 1 columns]
```

O valor da coluna `Temperature` não aparece, eu queria que aparecesse as três colunas separadas corretamente. Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você definir um separador, da certo.
Faz assim:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';', encoding="ISO-8859-1", header=None)
```

Uma vez que, aparentemente, as colunas estão separadas por ';'

Comment: Valeu, resultou!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o que o colega acima falou, mas procura observar a estrutura do seu arquivo antes, realmente parece ser o separador ';'.
Particularmente prefiro ajustar o csv antes, colocando o separador como ',' e ajustando corretamente as colunas.